# Maximizing the value of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, optimization, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

Let $f \colon \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R$ be a measurable, bounded function. Let 
$$
\mathcal A := \left\{ g \colon \mathbb R \to [0,+\infty): g \text{ is measurable and} \int_\mathbb R g =1\right\}.
$$

> What is the value of 
>   $$
> M:=\sup_{g \in \mathcal A} \int_{\mathbb R^N} f(x_1,\ldots , x_n) g(x_1) g(x_2) \ldots g(x_N) d\mathcal L^N(x_1, \ldots , x_N)? 
> $$
>   Is the sup attained?

Comment: If $f\equiv -1,$ then $\|f\|_\infty=1$ but that integral is $-1$ for all $g\in A,$ so there's no hope. You probably want to take the absolute value of the integral. Also, I would think you'd want $\sup$ in place of $\max.$

Comment: @zhw. You are totally agree, let me erase my wrong conjecture. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $E=\{(x_1,...,x_n):|f(x_1,...,x_n)| <M\}$. If $\int_{\mathbb R^{N}} I_E (x_1,...,x_n) g(x_1)g(x_2)...g(x_n)\, dx_1\, dx_2...\,dx_n >0$ then $M <\|f\|_{\infty}$. If $g>0$ everywhere then this says that $M <\|f\|_{\infty}$ whenever Lebesgue measure of $E$ is positive. Condition for equality depends on $f$ as well as the  support of the measure $g(x_1)g(x_2)...g(x_n)\, dx_1\, dx_2...\,dx_n$

Comment: Thank you, you argument is interesting. As a specific example, I would like to consider the case where the support of $g$ is (0,1) and where $f$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ computed in polar coordinates (e.g. in $\mathbb R^3$ consider $g(a,b,c) = abc$ and then $f(x,y,z) =: g(\cos a, \sin a, \cos b)$, where $a,b \in (0,1)$. Can you characterize equality in this case? Thanks a lot.